# how to compute bernoulli entropy?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, reinforcement-learning, optimization, probability

I am reading gail implementation code in openai baselines. they compute bernoulli entropy as one of the loss in adversary network loss function.

In their code, [they implement bernoulli entropy as this](https://github.com/openai/baselines/blob/master/baselines/gail/adversary.py):

```
def logsigmoid(a):
'''Equivalent to tf.log(tf.sigmoid(a))'''
return -tf.nn.softplus(-a)

def logit_bernoulli_entropy(logits):
ent = (1.-tf.nn.sigmoid(logits))*logits - logsigmoid(logits)
return ent
```

also there is a [reference of another openai implementation](https://github.com/openai/imitation/blob/99fbccf3e060b6e6c739bdf209758620fcdefd3c/policyopt/thutil.py#L48-L51), it's the same code but I can't see any explanation to it.

I checked that the equation to compute bernoulli entropy is:

$ -p\log p - (1-p)\log(1-p)$

I think the later equation is the right way to compute bernoulli entropy, but the first one should be right too as it's written in openai's implementationn. I can't see any similarity, is there any relationship between these two expression?

Answer (score 1):

Good observation, and yes, they are in fact equivalent ways of computing the entropy of a bernoulli random variable.

To begin, you have to notice that in the openai code, we do not have the value of $ p $ passed to the function, instead we have $ logit(p) $ which is defined to be:

$ logit(p) = log\frac{p}{1-p} = log(p) - log(1-p)$

Also, two formula to keep in mind. The first is the sigmoid function which is:

$ sigmoid(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}} $

And the second is the sigmoid of the logit which is:

$ sigmoid(logit(p)) = \frac{1}{1+\frac{1-p}{p}} = p$

*(i.e. the inverse of the logit function is the sigmoid function)*

Now we are ready to go from the first equation (used in the code) to the second equation (the generic equation to compute the bernoulli entropy)

$ entropy = (1 - sigmoid(logit(p)))*logit(p) - log(sigmoid(logit(p))) $

$ = (1 - p)*logit(p) - log(p) = (1 - p)*(log(p)-log(1-p)) - log(p) $

$ = (1 - p)*log(p) - (1-p)*log(1-p) - log(p) $

$ = -p*log(p) - (1-p)*log(1-p) = entropy $

Thus the formula used in the code is equivalent to the second formula you provided.

Comment: Quit exhaustive answer, but I'm a further confusion. I noticed in the [openai code](https://github.com/openai/baselines/blob/master/baselines/gail/adversary.py#L43) that they define logits with `logits = tf.concat([generator_logits, expert_logits], 0)` , how $logit(p)=log(p)-log(1-p)$ comes? And by the way, as the inverse of logit function is sigmoid function, why can't use sigmoid as activation function in the last layer? I noticed that there are direct usage of logits so they have to use tf.identity as the activation of last layer. does this kinds of logits has any meaning?

Comment: Sure, the concatenation just means that they are applying all the calculations in my answer unilaterally on both variables. As to where my calculations come from, whenever anybody refers to a logit they are referring to this agreed upon definition [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit). And finally, as to where they do that calculation, they do it at some point inside graph and the model tries to reproduce the value that a logit would obtain. It has a lot of theoretical concepts built into it so don't feel frustrated if it's still confusing.